# Best way to update the same file from multiple ansible roles

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I'm trying to write my first ansible playbook to setup my Arch Linux workstations and servers. So far everything worked fine but now I've run into a problem I can't really wrap my head around.

I'm trying to have multiple roles that require changes to the mkinitcpio.conf file, often in the same line.

At the moment I have a role **mkinitcpio** which generates the /etc/mkinitcpio.conf file based on a template.

*group_vars/all.yml*

```
encryption
  enabled: true
```

*roles/mkinitcpio/tasks/main.yml*

```
- name: Generate mkinitcpio.conf
  template:
    src: mkinitcpio.conf.j2
    dest: /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
  notify:
    - generate mkinitcpio
```

*roles/mkinitcpio/handlers/main.yml*

```
- name: generate mkinitcpio
  comand: mkinitcpio -p linux
```

*roles/mkinitcpio/templates/mkinitcpio.conf.j2*

```
HOOKS=(base systemd autodetect keyboard sd-vconsole modconf block {% if encryption.enabled == true %}sdencrypt {% endif %}sd-lvm2 filesystems fsck)
```

Now I have a second role **plymouth** that also has to update the mkinitcpio.conf, dependend if it will be installed or not.
It will have to add *sd-plymouth* between systemd and autodetect and notify *generate mkinitcpio* after that.

The solutions I came up with so far are:
1.)
Make the **plymouth** role dependend on the **mkinitcpio** role.
The **plymouth** role installs plymouth, than modifies the HOOKS line via the lineinfile module. After that, it notifies *generate mkinitcpio* if needed.

This solution will get very complicated, if more roles will be added, that may update the mkinitcpio.conf file.

2.) Add another conditional to *roles/mkinitcpio/templates/mkinitcpio.conf.j2*:

```
HOOKS=(base systemd {% if plymouth == true %}sd-plymouth {% endif %}autodetect keyboard sd-vconsole modconf block {% if encryption.enabled == true %}sdencrypt {% endif %}sd-lvm2 filesystems fsck)
```

Make the **mkinitcpio** role dependend on the **plymouth** role, so that it will install plymouth at first. After that, the **mkinitcpio** role will update the complete mkinitcpio.conf file and notify *generate mkinitcpio* if needed.

This solution does not seem right to me, because it has a "reversed dependency".

I hope I described my problem understandable and you can give me some tips about the best way to solve it. Thank you in advance!